# Java Streams | groupingBy same elements

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream of words and I would like to sort them according to the occurrence of same elements (=words).

e.g.: {hello, world, hello}

to

```
Map<String, List<String>>
```

hello, {hello, hello}

world, {world}

What i have so far:

```
Map<Object, List<String>> list = streamofWords.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(???));
```

Problem 1: The stream seems to lose the information that he is processing Strings, therefore the compiler forces me to change the type to Object, List

Problem 2: I don't know what to put inside the parentesis to group it by the same occurrence. I know that I am able to process single elements within th lambda-expression but I have no idea how to reach "outside" each element to check for equality.

Thank You

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The KeyExtractor you are searching for is the identity function:

```
Map<String, List<String>> list = streamofWords.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()));
```

EDIT added explanation:

- `Function.identity()` retuns a 'Function' with one method that does nothing more than returning the argument it gets.
- `Collectors.groupingBy(Function<S, K> keyExtractor)` provides a collector, which collects all elements of the stream to a `Map<K, List<S>>`. It is using the keyExtractor implementation it gets to inspect the stream's objects of type `S` and deduce a key of type `K` from them. This key is the map's key used to get (or create) the list in the result map the stream element is added to.

Comment: Thank You, I'll give you the accepted answer as soon as I've confirmed it. P.S.: Would you mind explaining how this works ? Especially what's the strategy when i would like to get meta-data of elements within a list when i use streams ? Somehow i don't seem to get it. I think this might be helpful for future readers.

Comment: Yes a little bit, just one more little thing: is "s -> s" as lambda expression really enough to imply that i want elements with the same identity. I don't get how to tell the function that i want the same elements. s -> s.equals(s) would be nonsense, right ?

Comment: Function.identity() is nothing more than `return s -> s;`. It is just a name for the lambda it returns as it reads better. And yes, it is enough for your purpose. `s -> s.equals(s)` would give you a Map<Boolean, List<String>> with all elements in the list at `true` (as all Strings are equal to themselves). Would be kind of nonsens, yes ;-)

Answer (score 10):

To get a `Map<String, List<String>>`, you just need to tell to the `groupingBy` collector that you want to group the values by identity, so the function `x -> x`.

```
Map<String, List<String>> occurrences = 
     streamOfWords.collect(groupingBy(str -> str));
```

However this a bit useless, as you see you have the same type of informations two times. You should look into a `Map<String, Long>`, where's the value indicates the occurrences of the String in the Stream.

```
Map<String, Long> occurrences = 
     streamOfWords.collect(groupingBy(str -> str, counting()));
```

Basically instead of having a `groupingBy` that return values as `List`, you use the downstream collector `counting()` to tell that you want to count the number of times this value appears.

Your sort requirement should imply that you should have a `Map<Long, List<String>>` (what if different Strings appear the same number of times?), and as the default `toMap` collector returns an `HashMap`, it has no notions of ordering, but you could store the elements in a `TreeMap` instead.

---

I've tried to summarize a bit what I've said in the comments.

You seems to have troubles with how `str -> str` can tell whether "hello" or "world" are different.

First of all `str -> str` is a function, that is, for an input x yields a value f(x). For example, `f(x) = x + 2` is a function that for any value `x` returns `x + 2`.

Here we are using the identity function, that is `f(x) = x`. When you collect the elements from the pipeline in the `Map`, this function will be called before to obtain the key from the value. So in your example, you have 3 elements for which the identity function yields:

```
f("hello") = "hello"
f("world") = "world"
```

So far so good.

Now when `collect()` is called, for every value in the stream you'll apply the function on it and evaluate the result (which will be the key in the `Map`). If a key already exists, we take the currently mapped value and we merge in a `List` the value we wanted to put (i.e the value from which you just applied the function on) with this previous mapped value. That's why you get a `Map<String, List<String>>` at the end.

Let's take another example. Now the stream contains the values "hello", "world" and "hey" and the function that we want to apply to group the elements is `str -> str.substring(0, 2)`, that is, the function that takes the first two characters of the String.

Similarly, we have:

```
f("hello") = "he"
f("world") = "wo"
f("hey") = "he"
```

Here you see that both "hello" and "hey" yields the same key when applying the function and hence they will be grouped in the same `List` when collecting them, so that the final result is:

```
"he" -> ["hello", "hey"]
"wo" -> ["world"]
```

To have an analogy with mathematics, you could have take any non-bijective function, such as x<sup>2</sup>. For `x = -2` and `x = 2` we have that `f(x) = 4`. So if we grouped integers by this function, -2 and 2 would have been in the same "bag".

Looking at the source code won't help you to understand what's going on at first. It's useful if you want to know how it's implemented under the hood. But try first to think of the concept with a higher level of abstraction and then maybe things will become clearer.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Would you mind to explain shortly how it is possible to gather meta-data of elements within a list when using streams ? I understand that each element is processed after each other, but how does it work under the hood ? The level of abstraction when using streams is kind of confusing to me.

Comment: @SklogW Which specific parts you have troubles with? The source code is not very simple to understand. For a high level picture `groupingBy` is a collector that accumulates element in a `Map<K, List<V>` when traversing the pipeline on the go. Remember that `str -> str` is a function, so basically instead of doing `map.put(str, someValue)` you will do `map.put(function.apply(str), someValue)`. If you have two identical keys you merge the values in a List and so on. The type information is preserved because `Function` is a generic interface so you know which type you'll get after applying it.

Comment: In our case `function.apply(str)` will return `str` because it's the identity function, so basically every string that is the same (according to equals) will be merged in a single List that contains all these Strings to produce the value associated with the key. That's why you have a `Map<String, List<String>>` at the end.

Comment: What i don't get is that s -> s is true for any element, how does the stream implementation know that "hello" is different from "world" when i apply only the function "s -> s"

Comment: @SklogW I think you'll understand better if I do a mathematical analogy. The identity function is, for any x, `f(x) = x`. In our case `f(1) != f(2)`. The same applies here. When your identity function is applied to "hello" it returns "hello" and when it's applied to "world" it returns "world". Hence `f("hello") != f("world")` so you know its not the same keys according to the function you provided.

Comment: Thx it's a bit clearer, but i think I'll have to take a look on the implementation. Thank you very much !

Comment: @SklogW For example try with the function `str -> str.substring(0, 2)`. When collecting the words "hey" and "hello", we have that `f("hey") = "he"` and `f("hello") = "he"`. So according to it, when collecting the elements, the key "he" should be mapped with the values "hello" and "hey", because applying the function to these values yield the same result. You'll notice that you are grouping elements by their first two letters here.

Comment: Yes it makes sense, I think I am kind of stuck in thinking in good ol' for-loops...

Comment: @SklogW To be honest, I don't think that looking at the implementation in the first time would help here. Try to think with a higher level of abstractions maybe things will become clearer as you pratice it.

Comment: If you still want to take a look , here are the relevant parts: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#Collectors.groupingBy%28java.util.function.Function%2Cjava.util.function.Supplier%2Cjava.util.stream.Collector%29 and http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java#ReferencePipeline.collect%28java.util.stream.Collector%29

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by some fields of an object, not a whole object and you don't want to change your equals and hashCode methods I'd create a class holding a set of keys for grouping purposes:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

@Getter
public class MultiKey {

    public MultiKey(Object... keys) {
        this.keys = keys;
    }

    private Object[] keys;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        MultiKey multiKey = (MultiKey) o;
        return Arrays.equals(keys, multiKey.keys);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(keys);
    }

}
```

And the `groupingBy` itself:

```
Map<MultiKey, List<VhfEventView>> groupedList = list
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                 e -> new MultiKey(e.getGroupingKey1(), e.getGroupingKey2())));
```