# Collectors groupingBy java 8

Tags: java, java-8, grouping, collectors

Consider these two classes

*Subject class:*

```
class Subject{
    long id;
    String category;
    String description;
    public Subject(long id,String category,String description){
        this.id=id;
        this.category=category;
        this.description=description;
    }
    // getters, setters, toString,...    
}
```

*Observer class:*

```
class Observer{
    long id;
    Subject subject;
    public Observer(long id,Subject subject){
        this.id=id;
        this.subject=subject;
    }
    // getters, setters, toString,...
}
```

And consider this list of observers

```
Subject s1 = new Subject(1, "sport", "subject 1");
Subject s2 = new Subject(2, "music", "subject 2");
Subject s3 = new Subject(3, "sport", "subject 3");

List<Observer> observers = Arrays.asList(new Observer(1, s1),
        new Observer(2, s1), new Observer(3, s2), new Observer(4, s3));
```

What i have tried so far and succeeded to do it is to group observers by subject as follow

```
Map<Subject, List<Observer>> observersGroupedBySubject = observers.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Observer::getSubject));
```

But how can i group observers by subject's category using the same above logic (`Collectors`, `groupingBy`, `method reference`,...)?

For instance, how can i get observers that subscribed to a subject whose category equals to `sport` using something like this

```
Map<String, List<Observer>> observersGroupedBySubjectCategory = ...;
observersGroupedBySubjectCategory.get("sport");
```

Thanks.

Comment: *"For instance, how can i group observers that subscribed to a subject whose category equals to sport?"* What is the result that you want? (Give an example output.) It sounds like you don't want groupingBy, you want a filter.

Comment: `groupingBy(o -> o.getSubject().getCategory())`. Or define `getSubjectCategory()` in `Observer` class.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou If you think that's what they want, post it as an answer. (Don't use comments to answer.)

Comment: @Radiodef I don't want a filter but a group by. See answer edited.

Comment: @Radiodef it was just a suggestion. Promise to use comments in apropriate way in future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.getSubject().getCategory())
```

or define `getSubjectCategory()` in `Observer` class and use method reference:

```
Collectors.groupingBy(Observer::getSubjectCategory)
```

Answer (score 4):

> But how can i group observers by subject's category using the same
>   above logic (Collectors, groupingBy, method reference,...)?

As I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29946938/java-streams-groupingby-same-elements/29947129#29947129) (the second part), you just need to provide a function that will take the subject's category for a given observer. So in this case it will be:

```
groupingBy(o -> o.getSubject().getCategory())
```

This will give you a `Map<String, List<Observer>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter.

```
Map<Subject, List<Observer>> observersGroupedBySubject = observers
                .stream()
                .filter((u) -> u.getSubject().getCategory()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("sport"))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Observer::getSubject));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i don't want a filter. Instead i want a direct group by subject's category.