# Why Java needs an argument for a method to correctly deduce generics?

Tags: java, generics

Suppose we have the following code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    private static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> Map<K, V> sorted(Map<K, V> map) {
        return map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
    }
}
```

A fairly simple snippet - we take a map and return another map that represents the same map, but sorted according to its values.

Let's change the functionality a little bit - instead of returning something based on an argument, let's introduce and work on a `static` object:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    private static Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    private static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> Map<K, V> sorted() {
        return map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
    }
}
```

Note that the only thing we changed was getting rid of the argument and, instead, working with a `static` field. One may wonder why then introduce the generics `K` and `V` at all - after all they will always be `Integer` and `String`, respectively. But wouldn't that mean that Java can easily deduce those arguments? Why exactly does it fail with an error of:

> ```
> Error:(16, 25) java: incompatible types: inference variable K has incompatible bounds
> equality constraints: K,K
> lower bounds: java.lang.Integer
> ```

I have seen [some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337231/inference-variable-k-has-incompatible-bounds) regarding [similar error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522741/incompatible-types-inference-variable-t-has-incompatible-bounds), but I couldn't get any information from there. Why exactly does this fail? It's maybe worth to mention that while the compiler produces the above error, when using IntelliJ IDEA, the `Entry::getKey` and `Entry::getValue` method references are highlighed in red and, when hovered over, the following message gets displayed:

> ```
> Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context.
> ```

Which is weird, since I see nothing alike in the actual error message from `javac`.

Comment: The type arguments are inferred at the call site. If you called `Main.<String, Integer>sorted()`, and this were allowed, you'd get back a reference to a `Map<String, Integer>`, but the keys and values are actually Integer and String, respectively.

Comment: @AndyTurner incompatible references at runtime (however, this would actually be inspectable during compile time) are nothing new, so in the case you introduced I would either expect a compiler error or a ClassCastException. I see no reason why something like that wouldn't be allowed, but I am completely okay with the explanation that the developers in charge opted for such design to, quite possibly, avoid tricky situations. So, basically, was it simply a design choice that the *call site* relation with arguments is as it is? Could you possibly rephrase it and post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concrete type arguments are determined at the call site.

For example, any of these are legal calls:

```
Map<Void, Integer> mapA = Main.sorted();
Map<String, String> mapB = Main.sorted();
Map<Integer, GregorianCalendar> mapC = Main.sorted();
```

...but, given the method definition, they would all return the same value; since they are of different types, at least two of `mapA..C` are type-incorrect (and, in fact, all three are).

The sole point of generics is to allow you to omit explicit casts; this is advantageous, because the compiler is able to reason better than you about whether a cast (or, rather, all the casts throughout the code) are safe.

So, if you write that a method returns a `Map<Void, Integer>`, or whatever, the compiler is going to do everything it can to make sure that it really *does* return a `Map<Void, Integer>`. Or, to put this another way, the compiler ensures that it returns a `Map` where every element of the `keySet()` can be safely cast to a `Void`; and every element of `values()` can be safely cast to an `Integer`.

Thus far I have only talked about *concrete* type parameters: `Void, Integer, String, GregorianCalendar`. But the compiler doesn't draw distinction between such type parameters and type *variables*. Thus, if you say that a method returns a `Map<K, V>`, the compiler is going to do everything it can to make sure that it returns a `Map` where every element of the `keySet()` can be cast to `K`, and every element of the `values()` can be cast to `V`.

The important point here is that this has to work for *any* `K` and *any* `V`, because, as stated in the first line of the question, the concrete values of `K` and `V` are determined at the call site.

There are only a small number of `K`s that an `Integer` can be safely cast to (`Integer`, `Number`, `Object`, `Serializable`); a `null` Integer can be cast to any other type, but the compiler doesn't know if the `Integer`s are `null`. So the compiler is simply saying "I can't be sure that these casts would be safe, so I'm going disallow them".

(A similar situation applies to `V`).

Your method only returns a safe value when `K` and `V` are `Integer` and `String` respectively, because `map` is a `Map<Integer, String>`. As such, you don't need type variables, as the method will always return a `Map<Integer, String>`.

```
private static Map<Integer, String> sorted() {
    return map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

(or it could be a `Map<Object, String>`, or whatever. The point is that you don't need type variables).

Comment: Stellar, thank you. The rationale you provided the the paragraph starting with "*There are only a small number [...]*" is exactly what I was looking for - a fair explanation of a design choice.